# AudioBuffer/AudioBufferSourceNode playback rate? (Web Audio)

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I know it's possible to change the playback rate of a audio tag (or audio js object) but I'd like to know if it's possible to change the playback rate and THEN get the AudioBuffer, or manually do the change on the array itself? (I know the audio object does some magic so it doesn't change pitch or sound distorted - how?!)

Answer (score 1):

If by "get the AudioBuffer" you mean you want the result of playing the AudioBuffer at a different playback rate, then yes you can, but not directly.

One way:  Create an OfflineAudioContext, create the appropriate AudioBufferSource and AudioBuffer.  Connect the source to the offline context and play the source at the desired playback rate.  The offline context will have the audio buffer of the original source played back at the desired rate.

Note that the playbackRate attribute for an AudioBufferSource does not preserve pitch.  If you want the pitch preserved, you have to do something else.

Comment: I have to speed up certain parts of the buffer - so I'll have to process the signal manually right? Could you point me in the right direction for that?

Comment: If you know what parts of the buffer, just create a new buffer with those parts, attach them to a new AudioBufferSource and offline context and process just that one part.  This may work so well if you expect to be able to concatenate the results together seamlessly.

Comment: I actually need the playback rate to increase at a rate, so this might not work for what I need - I need to increase the rate per 1/8 second

Comment: The playbackRate attribute is an AudioParam.  You can do a linearRampToValueAtTime to automate increasing the rate linearly.  If that does what you want, then you can still use an offline context (or script processor) to get the resulting buffer.